# install two android appication with one apk - example from google market

Tags: android, installation, apk, google-play, android-install-apk

I'm new to android development.I want to know something about android app installation.Is it possible to have two application in apk file.I mean if I install one apk file will it create two android app icons in launcher list? and Is there any real app in google market so that I can download and have some experiences with that?Please help me.
Thanks

Jeyanthi

Comment: please ask most specific question,do you want to develop app?

Comment: Yes i have developed two apps...But i want both of them get installed in a single installation.Found something in google search that we can make two activities as main and launch-able,I tried the same and its working fine in my device.Now my question is will google play allow me to have an apk like this?any example apps in google play similar to my requirement ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can only install one "application" with an APK. But you can have multiple activities defined for one Application. In your `manifest.xml` you can create multiple activities, each activity can do it's own task. An application , if seen as something that performs a set of tasks that the user needs, then an activity can also be considered as an application. In that sense, when you have multiple **independent** activities in your application, each doing it's own task, your necessity is fulfilled.

**Update:**
After you re-framed your question: Yes, I think it is allowed. Check out Go Launcher.Ex

**Update: Article**
[Android Launcher spam](http://androidandme.com/2010/07/news/could-launcher-spam-become-a-big-problem-in-the-android-market/)

The above article talks about whether applications that create more than one launcher icons. They have also given examples of applications. And also there are launcher spam applications that just create a load of icons in your launcher. But basically, it is very much allowed, Google does no check.

For technical details, just google how to have an application create multiple launcher icons, you'll loads of info.

Comment: yes sanjeev.As you said I have two independent activities.both have separate said of things to do.So I have kept two diff activities as main and launch-able and I could able get them in my launch list(I mean I could see two apps installed(from user perspective)).So far things are just fine.No my question is will google play allow me to have an apk like this?any example apps, in google play,which will result in more than one app installed(from user perspective) when downloading actually one apk.Thanks.

Comment: Yes Sanjeev. I tried installing Go Launcher Ex app.It created one icon only.But could see more than two apps in launcher list after clicking on the main app. Would be happy if I get any other example similar to Go Launcher Ex app.

Comment: Based on the apps that I have used, only Go Launcher does it that way. But I'm sure it is allowed. Google Play has no reason to concern itself with how many launcher icons your app creates or how many apps your one application really is. You are not causing them any damage, there is no such rule :)

Comment: Nice to hear such a info :) Thank you so much sanjeev.. Is there a place from where I could get some more information on this(I mean having two apps in one apk)?

Comment: @Jey: Updated answer. If it helps you, check this answer as the correct answer.

Comment: Thank you so much..I have been looking this kind of stuff for last 5 hours.You simply rocks.Thank you so much man..

Comment: No worries. You can accept the answer by clicking on the Tick mark to the left of the answer.